# Redundant navigation to current location in VueJs

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, routes

I have app with a search function and the initial search works from the homepage. When I try to search again, after the initial results have been fetched and loaded, nothing is returned and I have to go to another page in the app to search again. The search is done through a navbar which appears on every page and the results are returned to a specific view page via an unordered list. I would like to be able to search again after the list page is loaded.

router.js file:

The results are loaded on the "Beers" page.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: About,
  },
  {
    path: '/beer/:beerId',
    name: 'BeerView',
    component: BeerView,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/beers=?:search',
    name: 'Beers',
    component: Beers,
    props: true
  }

]

const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push

VueRouter.prototype.push = function push(location) {
  return originalPush.call(this, location).catch(err => err)
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  duplicateNavigationPolicy: 'ignore'
})

export default router
```

The page to which the results are loaded, aka "Beers":

```js
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Beers",
  props: ["beers"],
  data() {
    return {
    beersData: this.beers,
    
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.beers === null || this.beers === undefined) {
      axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_BEER_API_URL).then((data) => {
        this.beersData = data.data;
        this.$router.replace({ name: "Beers", params: {search: this.$route.params.search} }).catch(()=>{});
      });
    
    }
  },


  methods: {
    navigate(id) {
      this.$router.push({ name: "BeerView", params: { id: id } });       
    },  
  },  
};
</script>
```

The NavBar component:

```js
<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  props: ["search"],
  methods: {    
    async getBeer(search) {
      const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_BEER_API_URL}?q=${search}`);
      this.$router.push({ name: "Beers", params: { beers: res.data} }).catch(()=>{});
      
    },  
       
  },

  setup({ search }, ) {
    const beerQuery = ref(search);

    return {
      beerQuery,
      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();        
        this.getBeer(beerQuery.value);
        console.log(beerQuery.value);
      },
      handleChange(event) {
        beerQuery.value = event.target.value;
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: **Never** destruct props in the setup function. (don't do `setup({ search })`, use `setup(props)` and access the prop that way. [relevant info](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-setup-props-destructure.html)
You just destroyed any reactivity that the property "search" had (which could be the reason your search doesn't work properly).
Also *do not* mix options API and composition API.
Move your "methods" block inside the setup function and return any functions your template needs.
If you need the router use it like [this](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html)

Comment: Aside from that your issue is probably that you're already on the route you're pushing to and just changing some query, which will not cause the component to be re-mounted and seeing as you do some logic only when the component is mounted it might be that your changes are never triggered again.